# Javafx apply style class dynamically

Tags: java, javafx

```
Button fooBar = new Button("1");
Button zooBar = new Button("2");

    for (Node child : scene.lookupAll("*")) {
        child.getStyleClass().add(child.getClass().getName());
    }
```

I have a lot of Nodes and all of them need individuals styling. Now instead of repeating: `Node.getStyleClass().add()` the entire time I thought I would loop through all nodes and apply a style class with the same name as the variable. However, how exactly can I do this?

Edit: How do I reduce the amount of styleClass adds? Right now I need to do it for every node. I have 12 nodes (Hboxes, buttons etc) and its constantly growing which means that with the instantiation (new button etc) + the adding of stylesheets I have crazy amount of code.

Edit 2: Maybe my approach was wrong. Trying to create the gui programmatically wasnt a good idea. Im thinking of using fxml for complex guis now.

Comment: try `for( Node child: scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable()){//add styles here}`

Comment: @MichaelPickett but what about getting the variables names? I need fooBar and zooBar inside the add method.

Comment: You will have to set each child's id to what style you want, then use my above code and `child.getId()` instead of `child.getClass().getName()`. That should work. So for the `Button fooBar` you would do `fooBar.setId("fooBar")`,

Comment: There is no way to get the variable names; those are local variables and are not part of the object. (What would you expect to get if you had two references to the name node...? Or no references, e.g. you had done `somePane.getChildren().add(new Button(...))`?) I'm not clear how it would really help anyway. If you're really creating them all by hand (as in the code snippet), the code is already going to be verbose. As an aside, if every one has a different style class, you should use CSS ids instead of style classes.

Comment: Also, `scene.lookupAll("*")` will give you *everything* in the scene, not just the nodes you created. E.g. if you have a button, it consists of a region of some kind, a text node, potentially another node for the graphic, etc etc. Your loop would iterate through all of those.

Comment: @MichaelPickett Indeed but I'd have to do that for each node. So by setting the ids I would end up with equal amount of code or am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: As @James_D said, you will end up with verbose code regardless. It would be easier to set up your nodes using fxml, and apply the id's there.

Comment: So basically, you are barking up the wrong tree entirely, and this seems like an [X-Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Y'ou might want to [edit] the question so that it describes the problem you are trying to solve (why are there so many nodes, and why do they all need a different style - perhaps you can create them with more efficient code in the first place), instead of describing how you attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed. With xml might be the way to go

Comment: Note that with FXML, the nodes get a CSS id equal to the `fx:id` by default. But I still think that if you are creating so many nodes, there might be a better way to do it anyway (e.g. create the nodes in a loop, or at least define one or more method(s) that create them and set the id at the same time). But without knowing the actual problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: Well actually I was trying to reduce code that's all. I got more than 12 nodes instantiated. Then I apply the style...it's horrible

Comment: 12 nodes is not a lot. I would imagine you could keep this code clean just with normal coding practice (define methods for repetitive code, etc etc). Not really clear what your question is.

Comment: @James_D Im trying to figure out how to change my question. It seems clear to me. 12 nodes isnt ya but its definately going to grow as the interface is going to be fairly complex. In this case it might be better to use xml anyways. I have so many things like new HBox(). Then have to apply styles to them. Its really going to be bad in the long run.

Comment: @James_D edited question

Comment: I don't understand why they all need their own style though. Why? Don't you want all buttons to look the same, etc? (Or at least, *most* buttons...). That's the part that simply sounds like you're doing things wrong.

Comment: @James_D they all have a different color. Some have different padding etc.